# Python Selenium WebDriver Chrome click() is not working

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Pls help...
I can not click on the element.

HTML

[image: image HTML]

After expanding

[image: image HTML2]

```
My code
    clcik_on_privkey = driver.find_element_by_class_name("radio")
    Clcik_on_privkey = driver.find_element_by_name("331")
    clcik_on_privkey = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='331']")
    clcik_on_privkey = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[10]")
    clcik_on_privkey = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".radio:nth-child(11)")
```

the item is searched without errors(did a few ways), but if you add ".click()" on endin in any case, getting an error

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <label aria-flowto="aria8" class="radio">...</label> is not clickable at point (286, 562). Other element would receive the click: <div class="alert popup alert-info animated-show-hide" style="bottom: 0px; z-index: 999;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="alert popup alert-info animated-show-hide" style="bottom: 0px; z-index: 999;">
```

As per the error message, the above element is getting the click. It means the above html layer is above the radio button you are trying to click.

If you have closed it before clicking the radio, may be you need to wait for the invisible. You are trying to click before the alerts popup disappears.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.alert.alert-info'))
```

Then click your radio button,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='331']")
```

Comment: did not help, gives the same error, without ".click()" at end works perfectly.

Comment: Have u closed the alert pop up before waiting for invisibility?

Comment: there are no alert

Comment: What is this element then ?  <div class="alert popup alert-info animated-show-hide" style="bottom: 0px; z-index: 999;">

Comment: yes, I agree, my mistake,but  on the page are no more visible elements, please advise how to close this element.